# Как установить свежую версию nginx на raspbian?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, веб-сервер, raspberry-pi

Что указать в source.list? потому что когда указываю

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/   jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/   jessie nginx
```

То вываливается ошибка типа

```
 Невозможно найти ожидаемый элемент «» в файле Release (некорректная запись в sources.list или файл)
```

Comment: Может пробелов много?

Comment: не, это в вопросе только)

Answer (score 2):

> вываливается ошибка типа

естественно, ведь там нет, конечно же, сборок для архитектуры `arm`:

```
$ curl -s http://nginx.org/packages/debian/dists/jessie/Release | grep -i arch
Architectures: i386 amd64
```

---

> Что указать в source.list?

если [версия 1.10.3](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/nginx) из [jessie-backports](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Backports) для вас недостаточно сыра, то остаётся, судя по всему, лишь самостоятельная пересборка пакета.